# What is wrong with this LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have never done anything with LINQ before, however I have experience with MySQL.

I am on page 232 of [Microsoft® ASP.NET 4 Step by Step](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627017.do) and the book has started to talk about LINQ which is cool.

The book has instructed my to type my first LINQ query which I have, however it has resulted in 19 errors from Visual Studio, because the `where`, `orderby` and `select` commands are not recognised.

Below is the code from the book:

[image: bookcode]

Below is my code (in the form of a screenshot so you can see what Visual Studio doesn't like):

[image: mycode]

What am I doing wrong?

Thankyou

Comment: Have you added `using system.Linq;` and a reference to `System.Core dll`?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the screenshot (if you open the image in a new tab/Window you can see it in higher resolution)

Comment: What are you selecting from? In the example from the book they select technologyDescriptor from a list. In your code there is no any collections being used.

Comment: post code not screenshots - or at least code as well as screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Linq query, the TechnologyDescriptor tag wih the "<>" is barfing.  What you need to do is specify a named variable instance for an individual item in the technologyDescriptor list.  For example:

```
GridView1.DataSource = from td in technologyDescriptor where td.TechnologyName.Contains(".Net") == true order by td.TechologyName.Length
select td.TechnologyName.ToUpper();
```

You can think of this query as similar to a foreach loop that is looping over technologyDesciptor list and "td" being the individual record for each loop

Answer (score 2):

You have unnecessary angle brackets (<>) around TechnologyDescriptor, for one.

Answer (score 2):

You have surrounded your variable name, technologyDescriptor, with angle brackets.  Please remove these brackets from your code.

Answer (score 1):

It should say: "from **technologyDescriptor** in..." not `from <TechnologyDescriptor>`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable usage is a little off. Also, is `technologyDescriptor` a collection?

If so, change your code to:

```
GridView1.DataSource = from t in technologyDescriptor
                       where t.TechnologyName.Contains(".NET")
                       orderby t.TechnologyName.Length
                       select t.TechnologyName.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems with your linq query, the screen shot shows that you have a variable scope problem.  Specifically, you are using `technologyDescriptor` to refer to two different things.  Does your form have a control called "technologyDescriptor", or a field of that name declared in another part of the partial class?